# What's the difference between @Model and @ViewData.Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my view page, both seem work. But for `@Model` , visual studio tells me it's `WebViewPage<T>.Model` , and for `@ViewData.Model`, it is `ViewDataDictionary<T>.Model`. So what's the real difference there?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No there is no difference. In fact `WebViewPage<T>.Model` just calls `ViewData.Model`.

You can check the [implementation on codeplex](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1fa5fe9ce17f#src/System.Web.Mvc/WebViewPageOfTModel.cs):

```
public abstract class WebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage
{
    //...

    public new TModel Model
    {
        get { return ViewData.Model; }
    }

    //...
}
```